# Change the number of digits of p value on a ggsurvfit() graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggsurvfit()`, I generated this graph with the following code:

```
library(ggsurvfit)
survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, df_colon) %>%
  ggsurvfit() +
  add_pvalue("annotation", size = 12)
```

[image]

I would like the p value has 2 digits like 0.37. In the document of `add_pvalue()` function, there is an argument `pvalue_fun = format_p`. I just do not know how to specify `format_p` here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/ggsurvfit/reference/format_p.html) and [here](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/ggsurvfit/reference/add_pvalue.html) you can try this:

```
library(ggsurvfit)
survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, df_colon) %>%
  ggsurvfit() +
  add_pvalue("annotation", size = 12, pvalue_fun = \(x) format_p(x, digits = 3))
```

Comment: depending on your r version you may use `\(x)` or `function(x)`

Comment: Great, it works. Good to learn something new here. Both `\(x)` and `function(x)` are working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

using format() in add_pvalue():

```
 survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, df_colon) %>%
      ggsurvfit() +
      add_pvalue("annotation", size = 12
                 ,pvalue_fun = \(pvalue) format(pvalue, digits=2))
```

[image]